# How to prove that hausdorff metrics on a continuum generate the same topology?

Tags: general-topology, continuum-theory

We define a continuum $X$ as a compact, connected and nonempty metric space and we denote the closed hyperspace as $2^{X} = \{A \subset X: A\neq \emptyset \text{ is closed }\}$.

If $X$ is a continuum, the Hausdorff metric is defined in terms of the $X$ metric, so two metrics of X generate two metrics for $2^{X}$.

I have to show that all Hausdorff metrics on a continuum generate the same topology (provided that the metrics taken for $X$ generate the same topology on $X$)

For example I have the following Hausdorff metrics:
Let $A,B \in 2^{X}$

$H(A,B)= \inf\{ \epsilon >0: A \subset N(\epsilon,B) \land B \subset N(\epsilon,A)\}$

$H'(A,B)= \max \{ \sup \{d(a,B):a \in A\}, \sup\{d(b,A):b \in B\} \}$

and are equivalent metrics, $H(A,B)= H'(A,B)$.

I know the follow theorem:
Let $U_{1},..,U_{n}$ open subsets of X. Consider the family of subsets of $2^{X}$ given by

$\mathcal{B}:=\{\langle U_{1},\ldots,U_{n} \rangle: n \in \mathbf{N} \text{ and } U_{1},\ldots,U_{n}\text{ are open in }X\}$

where

$\langle U_{1},\ldots,U_{n}\rangle =\{ A \in 2^{X}: A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}\text{ and } \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: A \cap U_{i} \neq \emptyset  \}$

then $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the so-called Vietoris topology. And the Vietoris topology is the same topology given by the Hausdorff metric.

I don't know if I can use this theorem to prove what I need or is there another way to prove it. Someone knows?

I thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Usually, $2^X$ is reserved as a symbol for the power set, i.e., the set of all subsets of $X$. BTW, your text is completely not understandable, sorry.

Comment: It is true, in this case they are giving me this notation for the hyperspaces of a continuum, the set of all closed and non-empty X. I think  this notation is derived from there.
Thank you, I will try to make it  understandable.

Comment: Hint: If two topologies have the same basis then they are equal

Comment: Show that $H$ and $H'$ *both* induce the Vietoris topology.

Comment: It's AFAIK not necessarily true that $H(A,B)=H'(A,B)$. "Equivalent metrics" has a different meaning, it doesn't mean *identical* metrics. One of the things you have to show is that we change the metric on $X$ to an equivalent one, the induced topology by the corrsepondingly changed $H$ will be the Vietoris topology still.